# Transform: translate(0%,0%) causes element to be rendered incorrectly

Tags: html, css, web

Mind the following snippet:

```html
<div style="
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0.3;
  width: 11.4px;
  height: 11.4px;
  overflow: hidden">
  <div style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 6px">
  </div>
</div>
```

It renders a red circle perfectly. Now, if we take the same HTML and add a `translate(0%,0%)` style to the top div, the result shouldn't change, correct? Let's try it:

```html
<div style="
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0.3;
  width: 11.4px;
  height: 11.4px;
  transform: translate(0%,0%);
  overflow: hidden">
  <div style="
        position: fixed;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        background: red;
        border-radius: 6px">
  </div>
</div>
```

On Chrome 61.0.3163.100, this causes the circle to be rendered incorrectly, with straight borders. Here are screenshots of what I see on both examples:

[image: good]

[image: bad]

Why?

Comment: if you increase the width and height then transform need to be increase too if you use translate(1%,1%) this should work. but dunno if that answer the question.

Comment: what is `padding: 0.3`? If you correct it to `0.3px` it works fine

Comment: My guess, simply different rounding gets applied somewhere, when translate comes into play. The question I would rather ask in this case, is what made you stick a 12px wide and high element into a 11.4px wide and high one to begin with ...?

Comment: @CBroe I didn't. Somewhere (on a **huge** page) I had a big wrapper with a 9.3px padding, which caused a completely unrelated, 4px rectangle to be rendered 1px wrong, deep inside the page. You can imagine the amount of headache I had to figure out this was the problem. Now I just isolated it and made this question for the sake of reporting. I also guess this is a webkit bug related to some rounding somewhere.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when you give the outer div a blue background, the circle seems to be "escaping" that a bit to the right and bottom already, despite overflow hidden. But I guess you can not really cut overflow on a sub-pixel basis, so somehow those 11.4px get rounded up to 12px, and that the circle seems to exceed the blue background square is actually due to sub-pixel rendering. When you throw translate into the mix, even without any actual translation happening, that triggers a different calculation/rendering mode, it might have to do with rendering on CPU vs GPU, stuff like that.